# How to prove that atmost n/(2^(h+1)) node of any height h

Tags: heap

How to perform Amortized Analysis for Build-Max-Heap.
 In Cormen at page No- 157 it is given that there is at most n/(2^(h+1))
 of any height h.How to Prove this?

Thanks.

img  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LWLf.png

Comment: Sorry, but not all of us have "Cormen". If you want help, include the relevant text, and picture of what you're calling "height".

Comment: I have added link for the image.Please check it out.

Comment: Have you looked at Exercise 6.3-3? Or is that exercise the one that asks you to prove this assertion? See http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~ajl213/CLRS/CLRS.html for answers to the exercises in that book. The one you're looking for is there.